# Using Part 2 of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Hey I've been really struggling with the following problem any help would be greatly appreciated. My rep is currently too low so I have to paste the image sorry for any inconvenience!

I need to find the derivative of this equation
$$F(x)=\int_{5x}^{2}\sin(t^3)\,dt$$

Comment: Hint:  chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F (x)=\int_{5x}^2\sin (t^3)dt $$

put

$$G (X)=\int_0^X \sin (t^3)dt. $$

$t\mapsto \sin (t^3) $ is continuous at $\mathbb R$, thus $G $ is differentiable at $\mathbb R $ and By FTC, $$G'(x)=\sin (x^3) . $$

but

$$F (x)=G (2)-G (5x) $$

then by chain rule, $F $ is differentiable at $\mathbb R $ and

$$(\forall x\in \mathbb R)\;\; \; F'(x)=-(G'(5x ))\times 5$$

> $$=-5\sin (125x^3) $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $G(x)=\int_2^{x}\sin(t^3)\,dt$ then, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $G'(x)=\sin(x^3)$. Note that $F(x)=-G(5x)$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $${ F }\left( x \right) =\int _{ \phi \left( x \right)  }^{ \varphi \left( x \right)  }{ f\left( t \right) dt } \\ \frac { d }{ dx } F\left( x \right) =f\left( \varphi \left( x \right)  \right) { \varphi  }^{ \prime  }\left( x \right) -f\left( \phi \left( x \right)  \right) \phi ^{ \prime  }\left( x \right) 
 $$ so $$F\left( x \right) =\int _{ 5x }^{ 2 }{ \sin { \left( { t }^{ 3 } \right) dt }  } \\ \\ \frac { d }{ dx } F\left( x \right) =\sin { \left( 8 \right) { 2 }^{ \prime  }-\sin { \left( 125{ x }^{ 3 } \right) { 5 } }  } =-5\sin { \left( 125{ x }^{ 3 } \right)  }  $$